# Firebase complex custom domain for functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have my website `site.com` hosted on `Firebase Hosting` and a simple API on `Firebase Cloud Functions`.

Right now the API can be accessed on `https://us-central1-SITE.cloudfunctions.net/`

I know that I can use `firebase.json` to rewrite the function URL to my custom domain and do something like `site.com/api-function-name`.

Is there a way to redirect the API URL to a custom subdomain and keep the main domain only for the website hosting?

So I'm trying to make:

`api.site.com` => access API functions

`site.com` => access website content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Your `api.site.com` and `site.com` will be two separate sites, that are part of the same Firebase project.

See the Firebase documentation on [adding additional sites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites#add_additional_sites) and [setting up deploy targets for your sites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites#set_up_deploy_targets).